# Is there any equivalent for packages (Oracle) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

I'm converting procedures from Oracle to MySQL.
Is there any feature like packages in MySQL ?
If it is not there, what is the substitute for packages in MySQL ?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are you moving from oracle to mysql?

Comment: @zerkms: they probably ran out of money

Comment: very old questions but I was looking for this as well,  seems mariadb now has packages: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-package/

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately there is no equivalent AFAIK.

See this MySQL bug : [Bug #11696 - Please add CREATE MODULE syntax, or Oracle PACKAGE equivalent](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11696)

Answer (score 4):

Mysql supports [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html) - the namespace of this is at the database level - there is no explicit support for creating namespaces at a lower level, and the '.' scope operator seeprates databases and objects.

So there is no equivalent entity in MySQL to an Oracle package.

Comment: K.thanks for the response.But is there any substitute for packages.

Comment: "there is no equivalent entity in MySQL to an Oracle package"

Comment: k.thank you for giving reply.I would like to ask one more question.what is the substitute for to_number function in mysql.Is there any function has similar functionality in mysql.Could you plz help me out...